# Find if QDial was rotated clockwise or counter clockwise

Tags: qt, qt4, qdial

Is there any way by which I can detect if `QDial` (with wrapped property set to true) was rotated clockwise or anticlockwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let 0 the minimum and 100 the maximum of your wrapped `QDial`. If the difference between two consecutive value changes is positive then you have an anti-clockwise rotation, if not you have a clockwise rotation (you have to adjust it to your actual values)

You should subclass `QDial` and use the [`sliderMoved`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qabstractslider.html#sliderMoved) signal :

> This signal is emitted when sliderDown is true and the slider moves.
>   This usually happens when the user is dragging the slider. The value
>   is the new slider position.
>
> This signal is emitted even when tracking is turned off.

Connect this signal to a slot that calculates if the rotation was clockwise or anti-clockwise

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), this, SLOT(calculateRotationDirection(int)));

void calculateRotationDirection(int v)
{
   int difference = previousValue - v;

   // make sure we have not reached the start...
   if (v == 0)
   {
       if (previousValue == 100)
          direction = DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE;
       else
          direction = DIRECTION_ANTICLOCKWISE;
   }
   else if (v == 100)
   {
       if (previousValue == 0)
          direction = DIRECTION_ANTICLOCKWISE;
       else
          direction = DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE;
   } 
   else
   {   
      if (difference > 0)
         direction = DIRECTION_ANTICLOCKWISE; // a simple enum
      else if (difference  < 0)
         direction = DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE;  
   }
   previousValue = v; // store the previous value
}
```

Now you can add a function that returns the `direction` property of your subclass.